# harddrive problem (usb external)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Hey guys I am using a Maxtor One Touch 3 given to my by my uncle.  It is connected through USB2.0

When I plug it in, XP installs it and says "the device is ready to use".

But it dosnt show up on my computer. It dosn't even show up in disk mangement. I then install Acronis Disk Director (which detects it) but marks it as offline. if i try to change it to online, nothing happens. (actually the lights on the HD blink - meaning communication and goes back into offline mode). The lights on the HD return to a solid which mean "working properly".

Here is a screenshot:[image]

**Is there any way to extract the data off the drive? is the drive corrupt? sitll useable?**

edit: DISKPART screenshot:[image]

edit2: I ran Seagate diagnostic tool and this came up:

```
Long Generic - Started 9/10/2010 6:44:36 PM
Bad LBA:            0     Unable to repair
Long Generic - FAIL 9/10/2010 6:46:41 PM
SeaTools Test Code: 4
```

Comment: Is this a used drive?  How old is it and what condition is it in?

Comment: Only thing to try is remove it from the enclosure, it is possible the usb controller chip is malfunctioning. Connect it to a PC using another usb adapter, or install as a secondary drive inside a PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seagate diagnostics failed the logical block addressing section so while it can see the physical drive exists, it can't see or access the disk space.  I'd say the drive is likely toast, but you could try something like Spinrite.  The problem appears to be more at the hardware level rather than the logical.  I doubt almost any program could access anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

[testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is worth a try.

> TestDisk is OpenSource software and is licensed under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL v2+).
>
> TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software, certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy.

Answer (score 0):

I add this reference, which might relate to your problem:
[Restore factory Hard Drive Capacity When HDD Shows up as 32MB](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleid=1139&page=12)
which says

> We don't have a good technical
>   explanation for what causes this issue
>   to randomly strike PC users, but
>   suffice to say a portion of the drive
>   firmware known as the **LBA48**, HPA and
>   DCO records becomes corrupted.

This solution uses the [Atola Technology HDD Restore Capacity Tool](http://blog.atola.com/restoring-factory-hard-drive-capacity/) to fix the firmware - use with caution!

Answer (score 0):

I would try taking the hard drive out of the enclosure and connecting it directly to the system, just to make sure the enclosure is not the problem.  When you turn the drive on, does it make any unusual noises?